# RecyclerView android error - app fails when trying to run it on android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to create an app that displays a list of all user contacts, and im using **RecyclerView**. when i try to run my app it fails, i notice then the problem is in "activity_main.xml" in the lines:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: in this lines   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

Comment: Please, provide some logs, errors or more code

Comment: Given you are new, I would recommend you take a tour of stackoverflow before posting a question. Please share what is the error in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the xml file. need to replace

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
android:id="@+id/recycler_view" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

in this:

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to set layout manager in your xml or programmatically in onCreate:

`app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"`

or

`recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)`